# Change the rules in a CSS stylesheet with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, domdocument

I would like to modify the **rules** of a class dynamically in code (using JavaScript). I have a *styles.scss* file, where I have a .grid.grid-radial class. I would like to **add** and **remove** rules to that class using JavaScript.

```
.grid.grid-radial {
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(160, 160, 160, .6), rgba(160, 160, 160, .6) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(160, 160, 160, .6), rgba(160, 160, 160, .6) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(160, 160, 160, .6), rgba(160, 160, 160, .6) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(160, 160, 160, .6), rgba(160, 160, 160, .6) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
}
```

I understand that I can use [insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) and [deleteRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/deleteRule), but **what** am I calling them on?

> How can I get the reference to the *styles.scss* file so I can modify
>   its properties?

**Note:** I do **NOT** want to use document.querySelector('#.grid.grid-radial').setAttributes("style", ...)

Comment: Why not just create another CSS block and toggle the class attribute of elements?

Comment: Long story short, I am using Angular and Typescript and I am already using [ngStyle] for setting background-position and background-size so I cannot just change the style attribute of the element (it's complicated). I must change its class that is why I want to use insertRule() and deleteRule() but don't know what to call them on.

Comment: That is why I suggested creating another CSS block, and give it a meaningful class name, then toggle the class of your elements.

Comment: The users will be changing the colors quite a bit, so I don't want to create thousands of new CSS classes and linking the div to them every time a new color is selected. Could you refer me to some links on how to accomplish this? I am fairly new to CSS so I don't know how to proceed with your solution.

Comment: Why do you think you would need thousands of CSS classes? How many colors are going to be in this color wheel?

Comment: So basically the user selects a color and I need to change a background-image property in a class associated with a div. The problem is in Angular you have templates... I have the following code hard-coded in my html: <div class="grid" [class.grid-radial]="gridstyle=='dots'"... Basically the className cannot change so I need to change the class's rules in the code.

Comment: An element's class can point to more than one CSS class, so you could create CSS class items that just change the background-image property, then just remove and add those classes, leaving your initial grid-radial class intact. For example, using Twitter bootstrap CSS, a table element could have class="table table-responsive table-bordered etc.."

Answer (score 0):

You can access the style sheets associated with the page through the document.styleSheets property. You could search for a specific stylesheet by matching the full href path like so:

```
const sheet = Array.from(document.styleSheets).find(s => s.href === 'https://mywebsite.com/css/mySheet.css');
```

If you're confident you won't get duplicates, you can make it easier on yourself by changing the find function to use the short name:

```
const sheet = Array.from(document.styleSheets).find(s => s.href.includes('mySheet.css');
```

From there you can call sheet.insertRule and sheet.deleteRule, as you already mentioned.

One thing to be mindful of is that browsers themselves can't interpret SASS/LESS files natively. What should be happening in your build step is that the scss file is compiled into a css file for the browser to read. You'd need to target that css file for modifying the rules-- even if the scss file is published to your website (e.g. for source mapping), changing it won't affect the site.

Comment: 'mySheet.css' should be a relative path to the styles.scss file from the javascript/typescript file that the code is in correct? In addition, the extension should be css not scss. I am getting undefined for sheet and I trying to debug

Comment: Apologies. You could use the relative path if you're confident you won't get duplicates, or you'll need the full path (which is found in the href attribute on the styleSheet object). I'll update my answer to reflect this.